# Threading Timer for a Quiz game

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading

I have to do some exercises in my university with Python.So I need to build a quiz game. And the requirements are:

- Right answer get +1 point.
- Wrong answer get -1 point

The player has to answer each question in 20 seconds. If the player answers with more than 20 seconds, he gets -1 point even his answer is correct.

I just tried with `threading` and `Timer`. My code is like this:

```
from time import *
import threading as th
score = 0

correct_answer = 1
def sctn():  
    global score
    score -=1
    print(score)
S = th.Timer(20.0, sctn)  
S.start()  
answer = int(input("enter : "))

if answer == correct_answer :
    score += 1
else:
    score -= 1
print(score)
S.cancel()
```

I set an example for the correct answer. But when I run the code, if I type the correct answer more than 20 seconds, after that the score = -1 + 1 = 0, or if I type the wrong answer more than 20 seconds, the score = -1 -1 = -2.

Comment: Your title mentions threading, but you have no threaded code in your example. This is good since threading is overkill for creating a timer. However, you haven't asked a question in your question. Please focus on a very specific part of the problem.

Comment: Please don't completely rewrite questions as this invalidates existing answers

Answer (score 1):

You have too much code.  There are two cases: if the user has entered the correct answer in 20 seconds or less, he gets a point; otherwise he loses one.

The timer function doesn't need to do anything.  When you test for the correct answer, you can also test to see if the timer has expired.  Timer is a subclass of Thread, therefore it has an function `is_alive` that returns True if it's still running.

The problem with your original program is that once the timer expires, the answer doesn't matter any more.  But you check it anyway, so the -1 point from the timer function gets added to the plus or minus 1 from the answer-checking logic.

```
from time import *
import threading as th
score = 0

correct_answer = 1
def sctn():
    pass
S = th.Timer(20.0, sctn)  
S.start()  
answer = int(input("enter : "))

if answer == correct_answer and S.is_alive():
    score += 1
else:
    score -= 1
S.cancel()
print(score)
```

Comment: thanks you so much . it works with me. Today i find a example code . Could you help me to apply this method. I will update the new example code .

Comment: The question asks about tkinter, and tkinter has built-in features to run commands in the future. Threading adds complexity here without providing any extra value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after` method of tkinter to start a timer when a question is shown, and deduct a score if the user hasn't responded in time. If the user responds in time you can call `after_cancel` with the return value of `after` to cancel the job.

For example, when you want to start the timer you would do something like this:

```
def start_timer():
    global after_id
    root.after(20000, times_up)
```

This assumes you have a global variable named `root` which refers to the root window. Though, you can use any widget for this. What it does is instruct tkinter to call the function `times_up` in 20 seconds (20,000 milliseconds)

In that function you can reduce the score by one, for example:

```
def times_up():
    global score
    score += 1
```

Then, in the code that processes the user picking an answer, you can stop the timer and prevent the score from doing down:

```
def user_picked_an_answer():
    global after_id
    root.after_cancel(after_id)
```

If this function is called when the user picks an answer, it will compute the new score as well as prevent the timer from ever triggering.